# Data cleaning of csv file with many separated criteria

Tags: list, csv, data-cleaning

I am struggling in cleaning up and organize the file I attached.
I would need to "clean" the csv file organized in lists and sublists separated by different criteria such as : , comma and {. 
I need three columns that show: 
-in the first column the number that identify the profession such as "1.1.1.1.0";
-the second column I need the number that identify the characteristic of the profession: there are "attitudini", that has characteristics from "D10a" to "D9b" ; after that there are "competenze" from "C10a" to "C9b"
-the last column should report the value of each characteristic defined in the previous column, for example for the occupation 1.1.1.1.0, attitude D10a is equal to 60.

I give you a subsample example here with just two occupation but I would clean the whole sample with 786 occupations. If necessary I can send you the whole one. 
many thanks to whoever can give me some hints.

Best

Roberta

{ "1.1.1.1.0":{ "attitudini":{ "D10a":"60.00000", "D10b":"51.00000", "D11a":"50.00000", "D11b":"39.00000", "D12a":"25.00000", "D12b":"28.00000", "D13a":"45.00000", "D13b":"48.00000", "D14a":"70.00000", "D14b":"71.00000", "D15a":"85.00000", "D15b":"74.00000", "D16a":"50.00000", "D16b":"48.00000", "D17a":"40.00000", "D17b":"40.00000", "D18a":"35.00000", "D18b":"31.00000", "D19a":"40.00000", "D19b":"48.00000", "D1a":"80.00000", "D1b":"82.00000", "D20a":"50.00000", "D20b":"57.00000", "D21a":"90.00000", "D21b":"68.00000", "D22a":"0.00000", "D22b":"0.00000", "D23a":"0.00000", "D23b":"0.00000", "D24a":"0.00000", "D24b":"0.00000", "D25a":"0.00000", "D25b":"0.00000", "D26a":"0.00000", "D26b":"0.00000", "D27a":"0.00000", "D27b":"0.00000", "D28a":"0.00000", "D28b":"0.00000", "D29a":"0.00000", "D29b":"0.00000", "D2a":"75.00000", "D2b":"71.00000", "D30a":"0.00000", "D30b":"0.00000", "D31a":"0.00000", "D31b":"0.00000", "D32a":"0.00000", "D32b":"0.00000", "D33a":"0.00000", "D33b":"0.00000", "D34a":"0.00000", "D34b":"0.00000", "D35a":"0.00000", "D35b":"0.00000", "D36a":"10.00000", "D36b":"8.00000", "D37a":"0.00000", "D37b":"0.00000", "D38a":"0.00000", "D38b":"0.00000", "D39a":"0.00000", "D39b":"0.00000", "D3a":"85.00000", "D3b":"83.00000", "D40a":"0.00000", "D40b":"0.00000", "D41a":"15.00000", "D41b":"14.00000", "D42a":"0.00000", "D42b":"0.00000", "D43a":"0.00000", "D43b":"0.00000", "D44a":"0.00000", "D44b":"0.00000", "D45a":"0.00000", "D45b":"0.00000", "D46a":"0.00000", "D46b":"0.00000", "D47a":"0.00000", "D47b":"0.00000", "D48a":"15.00000", "D48b":"17.00000", "D49a":"10.00000", "D49b":"8.00000", "D4a":"75.00000", "D4b":"77.00000", "D50a":"5.00000", "D50b":"6.00000", "D51a":"45.00000", "D51b":"54.00000", "D52a":"85.00000", "D52b":"94.00000", "D5a":"55.00000", "D5b":"51.00000", "D6a":"70.00000", "D6b":"65.00000", "D7a":"80.00000", "D7b":"85.00000", "D8a":"70.00000", "D8b":"65.00000", "D9a":"60.00000", "D9b":"54.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" }, "competenze":{ "C10a":"70.00000", "C10b":"74.00000", "C11a":"90.00000", "C11b":"77.00000", "C12a":"70.00000", "C12b":"74.00000", "C13a":"70.00000", "C13b":"80.00000", "C14a":"75.00000", "C14b":"77.00000", "C15a":"50.00000", "C15b":"45.00000", "C16a":"60.00000", "C16b":"54.00000", "C17a":"80.00000", "C17b":"80.00000", "C18a":"35.00000", "C18b":"37.00000", "C19a":"10.00000", "C19b":"8.00000", "C1a":"90.00000", "C1b":"82.00000", "C20a":"55.00000", "C20b":"54.00000", "C21a":"5.00000", "C21b":"6.00000", "C22a":"0.00000", "C22b":"0.00000", "C23a":"20.00000", "C23b":"20.00000", "C24a":"0.00000", "C24b":"0.00000", "C25a":"0.00000", "C25b":"0.00000", "C26a":"0.00000", "C26b":"0.00000", "C27a":"45.00000", "C27b":"40.00000", "C28a":"0.00000", "C28b":"0.00000", "C29a":"50.00000", "C29b":"68.00000", "C2a":"75.00000", "C2b":"83.00000", "C30a":"35.00000", "C30b":"43.00000", "C31a":"85.00000", "C31b":"83.00000", "C32a":"70.00000", "C32b":"57.00000", "C33a":"45.00000", "C33b":"48.00000", "C34a":"25.00000", "C34b":"28.00000", "C35a":"75.00000", "C35b":"63.00000", "C3a":"80.00000", "C3b":"77.00000", "C4a":"75.00000", "C4b":"85.00000", "C5a":"25.00000", "C5b":"25.00000", "C6a":"35.00000", "C6b":"31.00000", "C7a":"85.00000", "C7b":"85.00000", "C8a":"75.00000", "C8b":"74.00000", "C9a":"45.00000", "C9b":"37.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" }, "compiti":{ "p1":"votare normative o trasformare in leggi le proposte di legge", "p10":"leggere i giornali e tenersi aggiornati", "p11":"nominare gli amministratori di aziende partecipate dello stato italiano", "p12":"partecipare a commissioni parlamentari", "p13":"partecipare a convegni, conferenze o congressi", "p14":"trasformare in leggi gli atti del governo", "p2":"svolgere attività istruttoria (interrogazioni, interpellanze, ecc.)", "p3":"tenere i rapporti con il partito di appartenenza", "p4":"partecipare a dibattiti e a trasmissioni radiotelevisive", "p5":"recepire istanze provenienti dal sociale", "p6":"tenere i rapporti con l'elettorato (favorire la partecipazione dei cittadini, divulgare i risultati ottenuti, ecc.)", "p7":"discutere o emendare provvedimenti", "p8":"progettare e avanzare proposte di legge", "p9":"condurre indagini conoscitive su alcuni settori particolari del paese" }, "condizioni_lavoro":{ "H1":"95.00000", "H10":"20.00000", "H11":"55.00000", "H12":"85.00000", "H13":"75.00000", "H14":"25.00000", "H15":"95.00000", "H16":"25.00000", "H17":"50.00000", "H18":"10.00000", "H19":"0.00000", "H2":"80.00000", "H20":"20.00000", "H21":"55.00000", "H22":"20.00000", "H23":"0.00000", "H24":"0.00000", "H25":"0.00000", "H26":"0.00000", "H27":"0.00000", "H28":"0.00000", "H29":"0.00000", "H3":"100.00000", "H30":"0.00000", "H31":"0.00000", "H32":"0.00000", "H33":"0.00000", "H34":"80.00000", "H35":"0.00000", "H36":"25.00000", "H37":"0.00000", "H38":"5.00000", "H39":"35.00000", "H4":"100.00000", "H40":"15.00000", "H41":"5.00000", "H42":"20.00000", "H43":"0.00000", "H44":"0.00000", "H45":"70.00000", "H46":"70.00000", "H47":"90.00000", "H48":"80.00000", "H49":"20.00000", "H5":"95.00000", "H50":"75.00000", "H51":"60.00000", "H52":"70.00000", "H53":"90.00000", "H54":"85.00000", "H55":"0.00000", "H56":"10.00000", "H57":"64.00000", "H6":"90.00000", "H7":"85.00000", "H8":"80.00000", "H9":"75.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" }, "conoscenze":{ "B10a":"15.00000", "B10b":"11.00000", "B11a":"0.00000", "B11b":"0.00000", "B12a":"15.00000", "B12b":"11.00000", "B13a":"15.00000", "B13b":"17.00000", "B14a":"30.00000", "B14b":"25.00000", "B15a":"5.00000", "B15b":"3.00000", "B16a":"20.00000", "B16b":"20.00000", "B17a":"20.00000", "B17b":"20.00000", "B18a":"50.00000", "B18b":"48.00000", "B19a":"55.00000", "B19b":"57.00000", "B1a":"45.00000", "B1b":"43.00000", "B20a":"45.00000", "B20b":"54.00000", "B21a":"15.00000", "B21b":"11.00000", "B22a":"0.00000", "B22b":"0.00000", "B23a":"40.00000", "B23b":"45.00000", "B24a":"75.00000", "B24b":"74.00000", "B25a":"55.00000", "B25b":"60.00000", "B26a":"10.00000", "B26b":"11.00000", "B27a":"70.00000", "B27b":"62.00000", "B28a":"60.00000", "B28b":"65.00000", "B29a":"65.00000", "B29b":"57.00000", "B2a":"50.00000", "B2b":"57.00000", "B30a":"95.00000", "B30b":"86.00000", "B31a":"30.00000", "B31b":"28.00000", "B32a":"80.00000", "B32b":"74.00000", "B33a":"40.00000", "B33b":"34.00000", "B3a":"70.00000", "B3b":"62.00000", "B4a":"10.00000", "B4b":"11.00000", "B5a":"85.00000", "B5b":"77.00000", "B6a":"55.00000", "B6b":"48.00000", "B7a":"30.00000", "B7b":"34.00000", "B8a":"10.00000", "B8b":"11.00000", "B9a":"25.00000", "B9b":"25.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" }, "gwa":{ "G10a":"90.00000", "G10b":"91.00000", "G11a":"65.00000", "G11b":"68.00000", "G12a":"90.00000", "G12b":"88.00000", "G13a":"70.00000", "G13b":"71.00000", "G14a":"80.00000", "G14b":"71.00000", "G15a":"95.00000", "G15b":"82.00000", "G16a":"5.00000", "G16b":"3.00000", "G17a":"0.00000", "G17b":"0.00000", "G18a":"0.00000", "G18b":"0.00000", "G19a":"55.00000", "G19b":"42.00000", "G1a":"85.00000", "G1b":"88.00000", "G20a":"0.00000", "G20b":"0.00000", "G21a":"0.00000", "G21b":"0.00000", "G22a":"0.00000", "G22b":"0.00000", "G23a":"0.00000", "G23b":"0.00000", "G24a":"60.00000", "G24b":"57.00000", "G25a":"50.00000", "G25b":"51.00000", "G26a":"85.00000", "G26b":"82.00000", "G27a":"75.00000", "G27b":"79.00000", "G28a":"85.00000", "G28b":"85.00000", "G29a":"45.00000", "G29b":"37.00000", "G2a":"60.00000", "G2b":"51.00000", "G30a":"50.00000", "G30b":"45.00000", "G31a":"60.00000", "G31b":"71.00000", "G32a":"75.00000", "G32b":"79.00000", "G33a":"65.00000", "G33b":"60.00000", "G34a":"70.00000", "G34b":"60.00000", "G35a":"55.00000", "G35b":"54.00000", "G36a":"70.00000", "G36b":"54.00000", "G37a":"75.00000", "G37b":"68.00000", "G38a":"45.00000", "G38b":"43.00000", "G39a":"25.00000", "G39b":"28.00000", "G3a":"40.00000", "G3b":"40.00000", "G40a":"30.00000", "G40b":"28.00000", "G41a":"30.00000", "G41b":"28.00000", "G4a":"15.00000", "G4b":"14.00000", "G5a":"45.00000", "G5b":"40.00000", "G6a":"50.00000", "G6b":"48.00000", "G7a":"50.00000", "G7b":"51.00000", "G8a":"55.00000", "G8b":"65.00000", "G9a":"45.00000", "G9b":"48.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" }, "stili_lavoro":{ "F1":"75.00000", "F10":"70.00000", "F11":"95.00000", "F12":"80.00000", "F13":"100.00000", "F14":"75.00000", "F15":"80.00000", "F16":"90.00000", "F2":"85.00000", "F3":"90.00000", "F4":"80.00000", "F5":"70.00000", "F6":"80.00000", "F7":"60.00000", "F8":"80.00000", "F9":"85.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" }, "valori_professione":{ "E1":"60.00000", "E10":"40.00000", "E11":"70.00000", "E12":"40.00000", "E13":"0.00000", "E14":"90.00000", "E15":"60.00000", "E16":"50.00000", "E17":"40.00000", "E18":"20.00000", "E19":"70.00000", "E2":"60.00000", "E20":"20.00000", "E21":"50.00000", "E3":"80.00000", "E4":"30.00000", "E5":"50.00000", "E6":"90.00000", "E7":"10.00000", "E8":"30.00000", "E9":"50.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" } }, "1.1.1.2.0":{ "attitudini":{ "D10a":"58.00000", "D10b":"50.00000", "D11a":"49.00000", "D11b":"49.00000", "D12a":"22.00000", "D12b":"25.00000", "D13a":"29.00000", "D13b":"34.00000", "D14a":"63.00000", "D14b":"58.00000", "D15a":"72.00000", "D15b":"68.00000", "D16a":"50.00000", "D16b":"50.00000", "D17a":"33.00000", "D17b":"37.00000", "D18a":"14.00000", "D18b":"14.00000", "D19a":"18.00000", "D19b":"20.00000", "D1a":"87.00000", "D1b":"78.00000", "D20a":"62.00000", "D20b":"57.00000", "D21a":"79.00000", "D21b":"71.00000", "D22a":"1.00000", "D22b":"1.00000", "D23a":"0.00000", "D23b":"0.00000", "D24a":"1.00000", "D24b":"1.00000", "D25a":"0.00000", "D25b":"0.00000", "D26a":"0.00000", "D26b":"0.00000", "D27a":"0.00000", "D27b":"0.00000", "D28a":"0.00000", "D28b":"0.00000", "D29a":"0.00000", "D29b":"0.00000", "D2a":"92.00000", "D2b":"79.00000", "D30a":"0.00000", "D30b":"0.00000", "D31a":"0.00000", "D31b":"0.00000", "D32a":"0.00000", "D32b":"0.00000", "D33a":"0.00000", "D33b":"0.00000", "D34a":"0.00000", "D34b":"0.00000", "D35a":"0.00000", "D35b":"0.00000", "D36a":"3.00000", "D36b":"1.00000", "D37a":"0.00000", "D37b":"0.00000", "D38a":"0.00000", "D38b":"0.00000", "D39a":"0.00000", "D39b":"0.00000", "D3a":"89.00000", "D3b":"82.00000", "D40a":"0.00000", "D40b":"0.00000", "D41a":"11.00000", "D41b":"13.00000", "D42a":"7.00000", "D42b":"11.00000", "D43a":"4.00000", "D43b":"4.00000", "D44a":"4.00000", "D44b":"4.00000", "D45a":"4.00000", "D45b":"4.00000", "D46a":"1.00000", "D46b":"1.00000", "D47a":"1.00000", "D47b":"1.00000", "D48a":"7.00000", "D48b":"4.00000", "D49a":"8.00000", "D49b":"7.00000", "D4a":"83.00000", "D4b":"78.00000", "D50a":"12.00000", "D50b":"10.00000", "D51a":"22.00000", "D51b":"23.00000", "D52a":"71.00000", "D52b":"65.00000", "D5a":"64.00000", "D5b":"67.00000", "D6a":"57.00000", "D6b":"57.00000", "D7a":"75.00000", "D7b":"73.00000", "D8a":"80.00000", "D8b":"74.00000", "D9a":"79.00000", "D9b":"73.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" }, "competenze":{ "C10a":"70.00000", "C10b":"68.00000", "C11a":"67.00000", "C11b":"66.00000", "C12a":"72.00000", "C12b":"75.00000", "C13a":"75.00000", "C13b":"76.00000", "C14a":"83.00000", "C14b":"79.00000", "C15a":"53.00000", "C15b":"50.00000", "C16a":"70.00000", "C16b":"66.00000", "C17a":"80.00000", "C17b":"76.00000", "C18a":"66.00000", "C18b":"64.00000", "C19a":"5.00000", "C19b":"7.00000", "C1a":"97.00000", "C1b":"84.00000", "C20a":"32.00000", "C20b":"35.00000", "C21a":"3.00000", "C21b":"3.00000", "C22a":"0.00000", "C22b":"0.00000", "C23a":"29.00000", "C23b":"24.00000", "C24a":"0.00000", "C24b":"0.00000", "C25a":"0.00000", "C25b":"0.00000", "C26a":"0.00000", "C26b":"0.00000", "C27a":"58.00000", "C27b":"57.00000", "C28a":"0.00000", "C28b":"0.00000", "C29a":"53.00000", "C29b":"57.00000", "C2a":"92.00000", "C2b":"84.00000", "C30a":"55.00000", "C30b":"55.00000", "C31a":"79.00000", "C31b":"78.00000", "C32a":"79.00000", "C32b":"72.00000", "C33a":"75.00000", "C33b":"66.00000", "C34a":"36.00000", "C34b":"34.00000", "C35a":"72.00000", "C35b":"70.00000", "C3a":"84.00000", "C3b":"79.00000", "C4a":"92.00000", "C4b":"85.00000", "C5a":"26.00000", "C5b":"30.00000", "C6a":"13.00000", "C6b":"15.00000", "C7a":"83.00000", "C7b":"79.00000", "C8a":"79.00000", "C8b":"72.00000", "C9a":"43.00000", "C9b":"41.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" }, "compiti":{ "p1":"progettare e avanzare proposte di legge", "p10":"curare i rapporti con le istituzioni", "p11":"curare i rapporti con rappresentanti politici, sindacali, economici e sociali", "p12":"emettere ordinanze o delibere", "p13":"organizzare o partecipare a eventi (convegni, comizi, congressi, manifestazioni, ecc.)", "p14":"organizzare/partecipare a riunioni", "p15":"recepire istanze provenienti dal territorio", "p16":"curare i rapporti con soggetti o enti esterni", "p17":"discutere o emendare provvedimenti", "p18":"formulare pareri o proposte", "p19":"gestire le risorse finanziarie", "p2":"prendere parte alle sedute del consiglio o della giunta", "p20":"tenere i rapporti con il partito di appartenenza", "p21":"tenere i rapporti con l'elettorato (favorire la partecipazione dei cittadini, divulgare i risultati ottenuti, ecc.)", "p22":"aggiornarsi sulla normativa vigente", "p23":"curare i rapporti con i mezzi di informazione", "p24":"gestire e/o coordinare le risorse umane", "p25":"istruire procedimenti amministrativi", "p26":"rappresentare il consiglio o la giunta regionale", "p27":"svolgere attività istruttoria (interrogazioni, interpellanze, ecc.)", "p28":"cercare e reperire finanziamenti", "p29":"collaborare con le autorità politiche", "p3":"partecipare alle sedute delle commissioni", "p30":"curare i rapporti con i rappresentanti di altri partiti", "p31":"esercitare vigilanza amministrativa su enti controllati dalla regione", "p32":"verificare i risultati", "p4":"organizzare il lavoro o le attività", "p5":"votare normative o trasformare in leggi le proposte di legge", "p6":"applicare norme o regolamenti", "p7":"far parte di organi istituzionali", "p8":"impostare, sviluppare o controllare la realizzazione dei progetti", "p9":"svolgere attività di controllo sull'azione degli organismi di governo" }, "condizioni_lavoro":{ "H1":"96.05263", "H10":"30.26316", "H11":"64.47368", "H12":"68.42105", "H13":"48.68421", "H14":"2.63158", "H15":"94.73684", "H16":"11.84211", "H17":"21.05263", "H18":"1.31579", "H19":"0.00000", "H2":"65.78947", "H20":"32.89474", "H21":"31.57895", "H22":"18.42105", "H23":"7.89474", "H24":"0.00000", "H25":"0.00000", "H26":"0.00000", "H27":"0.00000", "H28":"0.00000", "H29":"0.00000", "H3":"100.00000", "H30":"0.00000", "H31":"0.00000", "H32":"0.00000", "H33":"0.00000", "H34":"71.05263", "H35":"0.00000", "H36":"23.68421", "H37":"0.00000", "H38":"0.00000", "H39":"30.26316", "H4":"100.00000", "H40":"2.63158", "H41":"0.00000", "H42":"5.26316", "H43":"0.00000", "H44":"0.00000", "H45":"56.57895", "H46":"80.26316", "H47":"67.10526", "H48":"75.00000", "H49":"6.57895", "H5":"93.42105", "H50":"64.47368", "H51":"21.05263", "H52":"68.42105", "H53":"75.00000", "H54":"65.78947", "H55":"3.94737", "H56":"5.26316", "H57":"55.15789", "H6":"92.10526", "H7":"81.57895", "H8":"69.73684", "H9":"75.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" }, "conoscenze":{ "B10a":"13.00000", "B10b":"15.00000", "B11a":"3.00000", "B11b":"8.00000", "B12a":"8.00000", "B12b":"6.00000", "B13a":"3.00000", "B13b":"4.00000", "B14a":"29.00000", "B14b":"35.00000", "B15a":"7.00000", "B15b":"11.00000", "B16a":"5.00000", "B16b":"5.00000", "B17a":"5.00000", "B17b":"6.00000", "B18a":"51.00000", "B18b":"53.00000", "B19a":"43.00000", "B19b":"42.00000", "B1a":"57.00000", "B1b":"50.00000", "B20a":"22.00000", "B20b":"24.00000", "B21a":"1.00000", "B21b":"2.00000", "B22a":"11.00000", "B22b":"8.00000", "B23a":"39.00000", "B23b":"42.00000", "B24a":"87.00000", "B24b":"77.00000", "B25a":"54.00000", "B25b":"53.00000", "B26a":"7.00000", "B26b":"8.00000", "B27a":"26.00000", "B27b":"30.00000", "B28a":"26.00000", "B28b":"28.00000", "B29a":"45.00000", "B29b":"44.00000", "B2a":"37.00000", "B2b":"35.00000", "B30a":"87.00000", "B30b":"82.00000", "B31a":"30.00000", "B31b":"23.00000", "B32a":"61.00000", "B32b":"55.00000", "B33a":"25.00000", "B33b":"28.00000", "B3a":"43.00000", "B3b":"43.00000", "B4a":"24.00000", "B4b":"25.00000", "B5a":"61.00000", "B5b":"61.00000", "B6a":"55.00000", "B6b":"52.00000", "B7a":"22.00000", "B7b":"24.00000", "B8a":"11.00000", "B8b":"11.00000", "B9a":"28.00000", "B9b":"28.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" }, "gwa":{ "G10a":"82.00000", "G10b":"75.00000", "G11a":"62.00000", "G11b":"60.00000", "G12a":"74.00000", "G12b":"69.00000", "G13a":"79.00000", "G13b":"70.00000", "G14a":"64.00000", "G14b":"65.00000", "G15a":"75.00000", "G15b":"69.00000", "G16a":"0.00000", "G16b":"0.00000", "G17a":"0.00000", "G17b":"0.00000", "G18a":"0.00000", "G18b":"0.00000", "G19a":"39.00000", "G19b":"33.00000", "G1a":"74.00000", "G1b":"70.00000", "G20a":"5.00000", "G20b":"1.00000", "G21a":"5.00000", "G21b":"5.00000", "G22a":"0.00000", "G22b":"0.00000", "G23a":"0.00000", "G23b":"0.00000", "G24a":"32.00000", "G24b":"36.00000", "G25a":"66.00000", "G25b":"58.00000", "G26a":"80.00000", "G26b":"76.00000", "G27a":"88.00000", "G27b":"85.00000", "G28a":"91.00000", "G28b":"80.00000", "G29a":"36.00000", "G29b":"33.00000", "G2a":"50.00000", "G2b":"47.00000", "G30a":"14.00000", "G30b":"18.00000", "G31a":"70.00000", "G31b":"71.00000", "G32a":"47.00000", "G32b":"46.00000", "G33a":"71.00000", "G33b":"70.00000", "G34a":"64.00000", "G34b":"59.00000", "G35a":"33.00000", "G35b":"36.00000", "G36a":"68.00000", "G36b":"70.00000", "G37a":"50.00000", "G37b":"49.00000", "G38a":"55.00000", "G38b":"55.00000", "G39a":"26.00000", "G39b":"25.00000", "G3a":"25.00000", "G3b":"24.00000", "G40a":"33.00000", "G40b":"35.00000", "G41a":"67.00000", "G41b":"69.00000", "G4a":"11.00000", "G4b":"10.00000", "G5a":"26.00000", "G5b":"29.00000", "G6a":"46.00000", "G6b":"46.00000", "G7a":"55.00000", "G7b":"52.00000", "G8a":"38.00000", "G8b":"38.00000", "G9a":"61.00000", "G9b":"54.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" }, "stili_lavoro":{ "F1":"80.00000", "F10":"82.00000", "F11":"91.00000", "F12":"74.00000", "F13":"93.00000", "F14":"76.00000", "F15":"72.00000", "F16":"82.00000", "F2":"84.00000", "F3":"80.00000", "F4":"82.00000", "F5":"86.00000", "F6":"84.00000", "F7":"86.00000", "F8":"83.00000", "F9":"86.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" }, "valori_professione":{ "E1":"61.00000", "E10":"21.00000", "E11":"61.00000", "E12":"50.00000", "E13":"45.00000", "E14":"66.00000", "E15":"61.00000", "E16":"32.00000", "E17":"26.00000", "E18":"8.00000", "E19":"50.00000", "E2":"47.00000", "E20":"37.00000", "E21":"55.00000", "E3":"74.00000", "E4":"13.00000", "E5":"63.00000", "E6":"58.00000", "E7":"18.00000", "E8":"37.00000", "E9":"39.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.2.0" } }

Comment: way too much "code" here. you could shorten your code by 90% here

Comment: if you prefer I can send it to you

Comment: I think we need to see what the data needs to look like. You want 3 columns? First column seems straight forward, but 2 and 3 seem to be large strings of {Dxx, Dxx, ..... }

Comment: I can attach you an image of what I am looking for

Comment: Occupation Capabilities Level
1.1.4.1.1     C11a         89
1.1.4.1.1     C11b         70

Comment: is it somehow clear?

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't very clear, that looks like two different rows.
Can you supply how one row of data looks now, and how you want that row to look after transformation?

Comment: file:///Users/robertabenetti/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-08%20at%202.41.31%20PM.png

Comment: try to paste it in your browser. hope it works!

Comment: first column is the occupation i.e. 1.1.1.1.0 for example; second column is the code that classify the occupation features like D10a H45a B56b etc; the third is the number value after the features like "13.000000" or "61.0000". so the first row could be 1.1.1.1.0 | D10a | 60

Comment: Something like this?
`1.1.1.1.0 attitudini, D10a, 600, 1.1.1.1.0 attitudini, D10b, 510, 1.1.1.1.0 attitudini, D11a, 500, 1.1.1.1.0 attitudini, D11b, 390, 1.1.1.1.0 attitudini, D12a, 250,`
That would include the first 5 rows in csv format, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot attach the example of the file I have already cleaned for the first occupation and a picture neither.Btw forget about the word attitudini or later on competenze or gwa. the only things I need are number: the number of the occupation (1.1.1.1.0) as first row, the code that identify the feature of the occupation (D10a) and in the third column the value of the features D10a that is 60; this is the first row; the second row will be still referred to the occupation 1.1.1.1.0 in the first column but now the second column there will be D10b (another job's feature) and its value 51

Comment: I understand, check out the Answer I have submitted. Does it help?

Comment: I got more or less what you mean the point is that I have to do it for 784 occupations. If there is no other way, I will start like you suggest

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle a job like this, is with the wonderful Find/Replace feature in any run-of-the-mill text editor. (Ctrl+H is usually the hotkey/shortcut)

Start by trimming the fat,

- replace all **"** with nothing.
- replace all **.0000** with nothing.

The challenging bit is to get the first column inserted before every 2nd/3rd column value.
The quickest way would be to replace all **,** with **,1.1.1.1.0,**. But this would be putting the first column as the third. Simply cut the last one and put it to the beginning to correct that.

The issue with this approach is that you have more than just 1.1.1.1.0 as a first column value. If there aren't too many different values, I would tackle each "block" separately. Just cut the block out and do the previous find/replace in a blank document, repeat for each block.

Yes there is a little bit of manual work here with chopping and changing, but that's usually how it goes with data cleanup!

Finally, replace all **:** with **,** (for the 2nd/3rd column separation)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [JSON](http://json.org), not a csv.

> **JSON** (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate.

You can paste the content [here](http://json2table.com) to read it. 
(Notice that you lost a `}` at the end of the content posted in question.)

Send the file to *ningshen_zhang@163.com*. Let me help you to convert.
Or you may do it yourself. Here is the code in `C#`:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = "XXX/content.json";
            string savePath = "XXX/output.csv";
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            var re = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>>(json);
            using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(savePath))
            {
                foreach(var pair1 in re)
                {
                    foreach(var pair2 in pair1.Value)
                    {
                        foreach(var pair3 in pair2.Value)
                        {
                            if(pair3.Key.StartsWith("fk_")) continue;
                            writer.WriteLine(pair1.Key + "," + pair3.Key + ",\"" + pair3.Value + '"');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobertaBenetti The file you sent seems not correct. Compare the data after `"C9b":"37.00000", "fk_livello5":"1.1.1.1.0" },`, between the content you sent to me and the content you posted in question.

Comment: I send you the link where you can download the data under the section "Tutti I datti (ed.2006). the file I posted and the one I send you are not the same: in the one posted there are just two occupation, I the one send you 780. here is the link: http://fabbisogni.isfol.it/opendata.php?check%5B%5D=attitudini&check%5B%5D=competenze&check%5B%5D=compiti&check%5B%5D=condizioni_lavoro&check%5B%5D=conoscenze&check%5B%5D=gwa&check%5B%5D=stili_lavoro&check%5B%5D=valori_professione&codice=1.1.1.1.0&flag=&download=1&submit=DOWNLOAD

Comment: @RobertaBenetti Check your email.